# Probability of drawing two balls from a bag

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A bag containing 4 red balls and 5 white balls.
2 balls are drawn randomly from this bag without replacement.
What's the probability that both balls are red??

I did P(A)=4/9 and P(B)=3/8

So, the probability of both balls being red is P(A)*P(B) according to my book.

But why that multiplication occured?

I think the the probability of the 2nd ball being red is affected by the 1st draw. So **how they can be independent events?**

Please explain me this, as I think my concept about Independent event is not very clear.

Comment: If $A$ denotes the event of a red ball by the first draw and $B$ denotes the event on a red ball by the second draw then $P(A)=P(B)=\frac49$. What we not have is $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. This because the events $A$ and $B$ are not independent. The calculation of $P(A\cap B)$ can be presented as $P(A)P(B|A)$ (as shown in the answer of true blue anil). Here $P(B|A)=\frac38$.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the [general multiplication rule](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch05-rul.html), so you are actually computing $P(A)*P(B|A),$ as the two events are not independent, as you have suspected. That is why you reduced the denominator for the second term. Writing it as $P(A)*P(B)$ is not actually correct, *unless the event $B$ has been defined as the second ball being red, given that the first ball was red*

Comment: Thank you so much ✅

Comment: Glad to be of help !$\;\;$ :)

Answer (score -2):

You can solve it both by using the conditional probability and independence. The probability of selecting the first ball as red is obviously
$$P(r_1) = \frac{4}{9}.$$
Then for each of this selection there is a probability of selecting the second ball as red is
$$P(r_2) = \frac{3}{8}$$
as there are only 3 red balls left in the bag containing 8 balls now. Then the total probability is
$$P(r_1r_2) = \frac{4}{9}\times\frac{3}{8}=\frac{1}{6.}$$
Now, if you want to solve it by using the conditional probability,
$$P(r_1r_2) = P(r_2|r_1)P(r_1) = \frac{3}{8}\times\frac{4}{9}$$
which is exactly the same.

Comment: This is confusing. If $r_i$ denotes for $i=1,2$ the event the $i$-th draw results in red then:$$P(r_2)=P(r_1)=\frac49$$This in contrast with $P(r_2|r_1)=\frac38$